# PhoneNumberChooserTask Show Crashing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I started getting an error all of a sudden.

```
        PhoneNumberChooserTask chooser = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
        chooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(Chooser_Completed);
        chooser.Show();
```

Show() brings up the contact list, but then the application crashes.

> Message   "Type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass' cannot be
>   serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the
>   type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public
>   members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be
>   required."    string

It was working fine. This seems very sudden.

Edit: So it seems that this only occurs when it is the second call to NavigationService. If I call it from the MainPage.cs then it doesn't occur.   ....?

Edit: It appears to do something with NavigationFailed. Still plugging away ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an open socket and the Show() leaves my application. Turns out this doesn't sit well with my open socket *_*